# Is there a jumplist/tagstack I can traverse in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vim, ide

When you move around in vim through jumping (either through movements [moving across text objects like matching parens/braces, or moving by way of the `/` search] or through tags [go to declaration, etc]) you have the ability to go back to the previous jump/location in the file from before you jumped somewhere.

I'm slowly learning how to move places in Eclipse, like jumping to the declaration of something, but is there any way to go back to the spot you were previously in a file?

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Naveen's [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html)

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> : go to previous cursor position

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> : go to next cursor position

Works with <kbd>F3</kbd> (open type declaration) jumping!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fight your vi urges you could try [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) or [viPlugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/index.php/viplugin/)! ;-)

Comment: viplugin costs money, so I'm probably not going to get it.  Vrapper does some nice things-- but it doesn't emulate vim as loyally as I need.  I'd like to learn if there is similar functionality for moving through the jumplist/tagstack in Eclipse, or to hear insight from seasoned eclipse users for how they deal with the fact that jumping to declarations messes with where they were in a file.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to jump forward and backward on Mac OSX Eclipse.  Also, see the arrow buttons in the Eclipse toolbar in the below screen captures:

[image]

[image]